# How to change the style of just one item in a flatList using hooks and functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-component

I am trying to implement a simple flalist using hooks and functional components. I want the item clicked to get highlighted and if there was another item already highlighted I want it to be de-highlighted. Im getting a dumy data with the first item as already selected from an array of objects as

```
    const CategoriesData = [
  {
    id : "1",
    image : require("../images/pizza-icon.png"),
    title : "Pizza",
    selected : true,
  },
  {
    id : "2",
    image : require("../images/shrimp-icon.png"),
    title : "Sea Food",
    selected : false,
  },
  {
    id : "3",
    image : require("../images/soda-icon.png"),
    title : "Drinks",
    selected : false,
  },
  {
    id : "4",
    image : require("../images/pizza-icon.png"),
    title : "Pizza",
    selected : false,
  },
  {
    id : "5",
    image : require("../images/shrimp-icon.png"),
    title : "Sea Food",
    selected : false,
  },
  {
    id : "6",
    image : require("../images/soda-icon.png"),
    title : "Drinks",
    selected : false,
  },
]

export default CategoriesData;
```

I have included the flat list as component to a class component as

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fontsLoaded : false
  }

  loadfonts = async() => {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts)
    this.setState({fontsLoaded : true})
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadfonts()
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this.setState({fontsLoaded: false})
  }
  render(){
    //console.log(colors.secondary)
    if(this.state.fontsLoaded)
    {
      return(
        <View style = {styles.container}>
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle= {{paddingBottom : 20}} nestedScrollEnabled = {true}>
            
            <CategoriesList/>
            
          </ScrollView>
          <StatusBar style="dark" />
        </View>
      )
    }
    else
    {
      return (
          <Apploading/>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

the flatlist in question is as follows, although I am getting it to get highlighted on clicks and de highlighted on another click but cant seem to understand the logic I would need so that when I click on another item, the previously highlighted item is removed

```
const CategoriesList = ()=> (
  <View style = {styles.categoriesListContainer}>
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight :120, /*backgroundColor : "blue",*/  }}
      data = {categoriesData}
      renderItem = {(object) => <RenderCategories data = {object}/>}
      //keyExtrator = {(item,index) => index.toString()}
      horizontal = {true}/>
  </View>

)


const RenderCategories = (obj) => {
  //console.log(obj.data.item)

  const[selected, setSelected] = useState(obj.data.item.selected)
  const[selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(1)
  //const[dataupdated, setDataUpdated] =useState(false)
  //const [previousId, setPreviousId] = useState(null)
  //const[flag, setFlag]  = useState(false)

  // console.log("previousID in function:", previousId)
  // console.log("selectedId in function:", selectedId)
  // console.log("selected in function:", selected)
  // console.log("obj.id in function:", obj.data.item.id, "\n\n")
   const onPress = (id)=> {
     console.log("selected : ", selected)
     console.log("selectedID :", id)
     //setPreviousId(selectedId)

     setSelected(previous=> !previous)
     setSelectedId(id)


   }
   // useEffect(()=> {
   //    //setDataUpdated(previous => !previous)
   // }, [selected, selectedId])

  return (

    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>onPress(obj.data.item.id)}>
      <View style = {[styles.listItems, {backgroundColor : selected ? colors.primary : "#fff"}]} key = {obj.data.item.id}>
        <Image resizeMode = "stretch" source = {obj.data.item.image} style = {styles.listItemImage}/>
        <Text style = {styles.listItemTitle}>{obj.data.item.title}</Text>
        <View
          style = {[styles.iconwrapper, {backgroundColor : selected ? "#fff" : colors.secondary}]}>
          <Feather name = "chevron-right" size = {8}
            style = {[styles.categoryiconselect, {backgroundColor : selected ? "#fff" : colors.secondary}]}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got A Solution For You
Just Run This And this Is Very Simple That You Can Understand

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    color: 'white'
  }
});

const FlatListItem = ({ item, selected, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item.id)}>
      <Text style={[styles.item, selected && styles.selected]}>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [selectedItemId, setSelectedItemId] = useState(null);

  const data = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, title: 'Item 3' },
    { id: 4, title: 'Item 4' },
    { id: 5, title: 'Item 5' },
  ];

  const handleSelectItem = (itemId) => {
    setSelectedItemId(itemId);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <FlatListItem
        item={item}
        selected={selectedItemId === item.id}
        onPress={handleSelectItem}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```